# New to Programming----- Getting errors

Tags: python, import, module

This is Python---------
Hello, I am new to programming and am trying to learn. I have been following a guide to Python and am on the final project and i get a few errors. The main one I am having trouble finding the answer for is Attribute Error: 'module' has not attribute 'getUserScore'. This is when I imported something. I have read on this website that submodules are not imported automatically and I can't figure out how to import the submodules. My coding is

> import myPythonFunctions as m
>
> userScore = int(m.getUserScore(userName))

I have tried a few things such as, import myPythonFunctions.getUserScore and from m import getUserScore, and a about 4 or 5 more but most of them get syntax errors and my program doesn't even start. I would really appreciate help, Thank you. P.s. The reason that it is imported as m is because there are a few others that have m.___ but they don't generate errors. The whole program is a lot longer but this is the stuff that gets errors. Thanks

> ---Edit--- Thanks for all your help it worked!!

Comment: Are you sure you defined getUserScore in your module myPythonFunctions?

Comment: Without the code we can't help you - this is most likely an error in the module file, not where you are importing it.

Comment: Is myPythonFunctions a module or a python file like myPythonFunctions.py?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to define getUserScore but now I did and it does not have a red error anymore, only the blue error I programed it to say. So now at least I know my coding is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your directory look like?

Assuming you have:

```
- script.py
- myPythonFunctions
|-  __init__.py
|-  submodule1.py
 `- submodule2.py
```

Then for script.py to look like:

```
import myPythonFunctions as m
userScore = int(m.getUserScore(userName))
```

Assuming `getUserScore` is defined in `submodule1.py` you'll need the following in your packages `__init__.py`:

```
from .submodule1 import getUserScore
```

Then when you import `myPythonFunctions` you'll have access to `getUserScore`.

Comment: Another scenario can be that myPythonFunctions is a python file in the same directory. I guess, you should add that possibility to your answer too :-)